# How to get JavaScript date.getFullYear() into React

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React based app at the moment, and I'm trying to incorporate the straightforward copyright year so it's not hard-coded in. I feel like I'm missing something really straightforward, but it's stating that the name of my function within the class isn't defined - when it clearly is.

I'm assuming the date function is correct too - so if there's something wrong with that, please let me know.

Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Footer extends React.Component {

  year() {
    document.getElementById('copyright-year').innerHTML = ("Jon Nicholson " + new Date().getFullYear())
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="footer-section">
        <div className="footer-container">
          <div className="footer-site-links">
            <a href="about">about</a>
            <a href="newsletter">newsletter</a>
            <a href="product">product page</a>
          </div>

          <div className="footer-copyright">
            <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
            <p id="copyright-year">{year}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

And the error message:

> ./src/Components/Footer.js   Line 23:37:  'year' is not defined
> no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Hopefully it's really obvious, but I've been scratching my head and can't work out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: this is wrong approach to manipulate with DOM by js. If you want that, declare a date variable first and then getFullYear or declared variable.

Comment: This is React - not vanilla JavaScript, so different?

Comment: Thats what i tried to explain. Bad practice to manipulate with DOM directly in react. You should use state, function or ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is using year a state variable and adding it to the code

```
import React from 'react';

class Footer extends React.Component {

       constructor(){
       this.state = {
           year : new Date().getFullYear()
       }
     }

render() {

  return (

      <div className="footer-section">
        <div className="footer-container">
          <div className="footer-site-links">
            <a href="about">about</a>
            <a href="newsletter">newsletter</a>
            <a href="product">product page</a>
          </div>

          <div className="footer-copyright">
            <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
            <p id="copyright-year">{"Jon Nicholson " + this.state.year}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the constructor method isn't exactly right but the concept is. Appreciated!

Comment: yeah i missed to brackets :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, keeping is simple, and avoiding using state or DOM-manipulation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    
    let year = "Jon Nicholson " + new Date().getFullYear();
    
    return (

      <div className="footer-section">
        <div className="footer-container">
          <div className="footer-site-links">
            <a href="about">about</a>
            <a href="newsletter">newsletter</a>
            <a href="product">product page</a>
          </div>

          <div className="footer-copyright">
            <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
            <p id="copyright-year">{year}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

function YearCopyright() {
  return  <p id="copyright-year">Jon Nicholson  {new Date().getFullYear()}</p>;
}

class Footer extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="footer-section">
        <div className="footer-container">
          <div className="footer-site-links">
            <a href="about">about</a>
            <a href="newsletter">newsletter</a>
            <a href="product">product page</a>
          </div>

          <div className="footer-copyright">
            <i class="far fa-copyright"></i>
            <YearCopyright />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: That's how you incorporate JavaScript into React?

Comment: You can use javascript at any point in React. In html you just have to add {} brackets around javascript. The way you were using year in your code was wrong i.e., calling a function from an html tag with {year}

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it in react js

```
 <div className="copyright">
  <span>Copyright © yourwebsite {new Date().getFullYear()}</span>
 </div>
```